# Inno Setup: Set default value for desktop icon-check box to true

Tags: inno-setup

I am struggling with getting Inno Setup to set the check box to true whether a desktop icon should be created. The documentation has not been any helpful concerning this issue as well as Googlism and Stackoverflow.

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
```

My thought was a value like "checked" for "Flags" but the documentation told me, that Flags isn't responsible for this.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

They are checked by default, remove the `Flags: unchecked`.

Comment: Thank you, very much. Since this option doesn't not have an effect on the setup routine on my workstation, at least it does on all others we checked on. Cheers!

Comment: Your welcome, it may be different on your machine because of `UsePreviousSetupType` which *may be remembering your last choice.

Comment: I found that it didn't work on my workstation in the first place as well, but it seems that Inno Setup remembers values of earlier installations. Uninstall your setup, reinstall and you should be fine.

Answer (score 17):

At startup Setup will look in the registry to see if the same application is already installed, and if so, it will use the task settings of the previous installation as the default settings presented to the user in the wizard.

To prevent that behavior use `UsePreviousTasks=no`.

Documented [here.](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_useprevioussetuptype)